# How to add a space when adding two variables?

Tags: variables, swift

I know this is a super easy question but I seem to have forgotten how to insert a space when adding two variables (it has been a while since I started coding again)

```
var saveName = firstName.text + lastName.text
```

Say `firstName.text = First` and `lastName.text = Last`

When I tell my app to display saveName, `FirstLast` comes out. How can I add a space in between without creating a dummy variable?

I'm using swift.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either

```
let saveName = firstName.text + " " + lastName.text
```

or, using string interpolation:

```
let saveName = "\(firstName.text) \(lastName.text)"
```

Comment: or, if you’re really bored, `" ".join([firstName, secondName])`

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstName = "Russell"
var lastName = "Cardwell"
print(firstName + " " + lastName)
```